# How to integrate Galen reports in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, galen

I've started to use Galen framework to test the layout of my website pages and I also have my other test, written in Selenium, integrated into Jenkins.
I'm using Java+JUnit+Maven and I would like to know if anyone has managed to integrate the Galen reporting into Jenkins and how.
Because for the moment I am using something like:

```
assertThat(layoutReport.errors(), is(0));
```

which tells me if there were errors in the tests but not where.
Thanks!

P.S. If someone with reputation could make the tag galen-framework so that we can group these type of questions, it would be great :D

Answer (score 2):

In your case you could use Galen for generating HTML reports as it normally does when you run tests with it. Though you will have to manage the creation of `GalenTestInfo` objects.
Here is how the HTML report generation works. Imagine you have somewhere `obtainAllTests` method defined which returns a list of all executed tests.

```
List<GalenTestInfo> tests = obtainAllTests();
new HtmlReportBuilder().build(tests, "target/galen-html-reports");
```

Somewhere in your code you could create a `GalenTestInfo` and add it to some collection:

```
 GalenTestInfo testInfo = GalenTestInfo.fromString("Here goes the name of your test");
```

Once you have done the layout checking and obtained `LayoutReport` object you could add this report to the report of the test. Here is how you can do it:

```
 LayoutReport layoutReport = Galen.checkLayout(driver, 
      specPath, includedTags, null, 
      new Properties(), null);

 testInfo.getReport().layout(layoutReport, "A title for your layout check");
```

You can find more insights in this project https://github.com/galenframework/galen-sample-java-tests. It has a basic setup for Galen tests in Java + TestNG + Maven. The reports in it are collected in a singleton `GalenReportsContainer`. There is also a reporter implemented in `GalenReportingListener` which takes all those tests from `GalenReportsContainer` and generates HTML reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a full example for Java (TestNG and JUnit) and JavaScript here: 
https://github.com/hypery2k/galen_samples.

I use the [HTML Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) together with Jenkins, see example [here](https://martinreinhardt-online.de/jenkins/job/Galen_sample_JUnit/)

Comment: The example link does not work. Could you please update it?